# LWC: Show content in full page width without headers

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to show my Lightning web component in full page width and height, means, removing the entire header above my LWC. Is that even possible? I saw solutions with Visualforce but i need to implement it with LWC.

[image]

The image shows the so called header in salesforce, how to get this removed with LWC, i assume i could do this with a custom app. But am not sure where exactly to tell to remove the header.

Comment: Did you try Lwc on community? There you can show full page width without headers.

Comment: cannot use community. its a simple lightning app i need to create, it runs as a custom tab, but i need to switch to full screen in some cases.

Comment: User your lwc component inside Aura Application

Answer (score 1):

Create a standalone Lightning App

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:lwc/>
</aura:application>
```

and launch it using a URL Button from your page. When aura application is launched in a new tab it will not have headers. It will just contain your components.

[image: Custom Button or Link Detail]